# Double scroll bars kept showing in Windows browsers

Tags: css

I use **tlk** chat integration, and I kept seeing 2 scrollbars only on Windows Firefox + IE.

`tlk` allow me to put a custom CSS to their chat.

I did some research and I've tried all of these below trying to prevent it, but none of them CSS seem to work. On top of my HTML file, I've added

```
//html, body {height:100% !important;}
// html { overflow-y: scroll !important ;}
// * html .clearfix { height: 1% !important; }
// html {overflow-y: hidden !important; }
```

Fiddle = https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/yrq93jyy/show/

If you view it on a Windows, you will see this like me

[image]

How can I debug this?

Comment: You should already know that you need to post a minimal work example of the markup that shows the problem. You have given us nothing to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has absolutely nothing to do with laravel nor PHP.

The element #tlkio has a CSS rule `overflow: auto;` which is differently interpreted by different browsers. To override it, you can do something like this:

```
#tlkio {overflow: hidden !important}
```

Ideally, you'd change the original rule without overriding it, but I assume you can't do it since it's a third-party integration.

Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/yrq93jyy/1/